# How to remove bulk edit options

Tags: posts, wp-admin, bulk

Is it possible to completely disable Bulk Edit functionality?

I'm using Wordpress 3.1.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by Bulk Edit Functionaity

Comment: in wp-admin go to the edit.php page (the page that lists all the posts) and then select edit in the bulk actions list/ It has options for categories, tags, etc which i don't need them to modify

Comment: nope do not think its possible

Comment: how do to disable rank math bulks ?

Comment: @SQROM don't post comments or questions as the solution to other peoples answers. As an aside this Q has nothing to do with Rank Math, and 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here, you should ask in a Rank Math community or via their official support routes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A more reliable approach than messing with CSS would be to add some Javascript in the admin_head action, and basically override the built-in "inlineEditPost" function (located in wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js and easier to read in inline-edit-post.dev.js). I haven't looked into it much specifically, but the brute force method would be to copy (and rename) that entire function and basically reverse the show/hide methods.

I've confirmed that disabling Javascript disables the Bulk Edit functionality entirely, so there wouldn't really be a workaround to your override.

Answer (score 10):

```
   add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-weddings', 'remove_from_bulk_actions' );
    function remove_from_bulk_actions( $actions ){
        unset( $actions[ 'edit' ] );
        return $actions;
    }
```

Change "weddings" with the custom post name, if no custom post just use "post".

Answer (score 5):

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'edit-post', '__return_empty_array' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'upload', '__return_empty_array' );
```

That will do the job

Comment: If this isn't working, you may need to set a priority, e.g. `add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'edit-post', '__return_empty_array', 99 );`

Answer (score 2):

You can completely disable bulk edit input by removing all actions from this filter:

```
function removeBulkActionsInput ($actions) {
        // remove all actions
        return array();
}
add_filter ('bulk_actions-edit-' . POST_TYPE, 'removeBulkActionsInput' );
```

POST_TYPE ist your custom post type as string or e.g. 'post' for usual posts.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible at this time. It's part of the Wordpress core and don't think there's a hook function to turn it off.

Comment: I figured that might be true. I could disable it with some css I suppose, but that's not a fool proof solution.